# Puppeteer, Debian 11, Loading chunk failed on Odds Portal scraping

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I'm using puppeteer to scrape match data from https://www.oddsportal.com/
I'm developing my project on Windows 10 and here everything works well.

But I want my program to run on my Debian 11 server. But when I run my program on my server, with headless Chromium browser, I get these errors more or less 3 over 4 times when I load an Odds portal page:

```
{
    message: 'Loading chunk 4402 failed.\n' +
    '(error: https://www.oddsportal.com/res/public/js/build/4402.be189ee4615a6b8d.js)',
    name: 'ChunkLoadError',
    type: 'error',
    request: 'https://www.oddsportal.com/res/public/js/build/4402.be189ee4615a6b8d.js'
}
```

with multiple chunks

and:

```
{                                                                                     
   config: {                                                                                                     
     url: '/ajax-max-odds/all/',                                                                                 
     method: 'get',                                                                                              
     headers: {                                                                                                  
       Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',                                                              
       'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',                                                                     
       'X-XSRF-TOKEN': 'eyJpdiI6IkEyZFdweitieTdReGpIQ01Uc2ozZVE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiM2VqZEhqM0FES3B0czZ0K2ZZTCtJc1VIa
XVFc2NqMWJsRXYwOEJyaDhDTnBlTy84SkltVnBaNW5sRDdvdlNZV2RnQnJSdVpodEFVNFgzOGhSeWpnMVRKdmtvaVlKRWJGZyswc0JQYW9EY01EVG
U4YmMyODMxNDIxMDlmNGZiODJjOWViYTRjMDM2OTdhMTZjNmE4NGFhNGE1ZjkzZGZlYTI3N2VhIiwidGFnIjoiIn0='                      
     },                                                                                                          
     transformRequest: [ {} ],                                                                                   
     transformResponse: [ {} ],                                                                                  
     timeout: 0,                                                                                                 
     adapter: {},                                                                                                
     xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',                                                                               
     xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',                                                                             
     maxContentLength: -1,                                                                                       
     maxBodyLength: -1,                                                                                          
     validateStatus: {},                                                                                         
     transitional: {                                                                                             
       silentJSONParsing: true,                                                                                  
       forcedJSONParsing: true,                                                                                  
       clarifyTimeoutError: false                                                                                
     }                                                                                                           
   },                                                                                                            
   request: {},                                                                                                  
   response: {                                                                                                   
     data: '',                                                                                                   
     status: 520,                                                                                                
     statusText: '',                                                                                             
     headers: {                                                                                                  
       'accept-ranges': 'bytes',                                                                                 
       age: '0',                                                                                                 
       date: 'Thu, 02 Nov 2023 21:35:34 GMT',                                                                    
       server: 'nginx',                                                                                          
       'x-cache': 'uncached',                                                                                    
       'x-deliver': 'Thu, 02 Nov 2023 21:35:34 GMT'                                                              
     },                                                                                                          
     config: {                                                                                                   
       url: '/ajax-max-odds/all/',                                                                               
       method: 'get',                                                                                            
       headers: [Object],                                                                                        
       transformRequest: [Array],                                                                                
       transformResponse: [Array],                                                                               
       timeout: 0,                                                                                               
       adapter: {},                                                                                              
       xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',                                                                             
       xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',                                                                           
       maxContentLength: -1,                                                                                     
       maxBodyLength: -1,                                                                                        
       validateStatus: {},                                                                                       
       transitional: [Object]                                                                                    
     },                                                                                                          
     request: {}                                                                                                 
   },                                                                                                            
   isAxiosError: true,                                                                                           
   toJSON: {}                                                                                                    }
```

My server is only headless, so I can't know if this is linked, but working perfectly headless on Windows. I also tried a lot of different browser args but no one solved my problem.

The thing is:

- Why is this working well on Windows and not with Debian?
- When I reload the page, sometimes it works, sometimes not -> why?
- Is there a way to fix it ?

Thanks for your help!

**EDIT:**

The errors are logs from the browser and not puppeteer errors. And when I get errors, the page never loads.

I get the error executing only:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: 'new',
    args: [
        '--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox', '--incognito', 
        '--disable-web-security'
    ],
    defaultViewport: {
        width: 1480,
        height: 800
    }
});
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto(url);
await page.waitForTimeout(300000);
```

I tried with the same code with playwright, and the result is the same, but a bit less frequently. So I think this is not linked to puppeteer.

Comment: I guess you're looking for someone else who has had the exact same problem with the exact same website?  There's not enough info otherwise to make any suggestions.

Comment: Usually when your code sometimes works and sometimes doesn't, your code is failing to match event-driven predicates with the state on the page. If you're using timeouts, that's a typical factor in flakey Puppeteer scripts. Some pages are complex, and you'll need to be very careful to make sure you've accounted for all possible situations that may arise and things being nondeterministic or taking longer to occur than you may assume. As mentioned above, please share your code.

Comment: I edited it @James, but it seems the code is not really important.